# SimpleWebRTC : how to close a broacast correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I'm using the SimpleWebRTC API but in the tutorials there is no place we talk about disconnection. How can i stop a broadcast ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want (terminate either one peer or all of them) either leaveRoom() or call the peers end() method. Can you file an issue with more details [here](https://github.com/andyet/simplewebrtc/issues) if that does not help?